# Rcarousel using lightbox and AJAX (call to a PHP page)

Tags: jquery, ajax, widget, lightbox, carousel

I am using the plugin Rcarousel (http://ryrych.github.io/rcarousel/) with Lightbox that is provided from that site, and all the defaults work fine. I have modified it to use Ajax so that the user can select from a number of images (which are links to different galleries) which then uses an ajax call to load the carousel. That works for the most part. On loadup I have one of the images called and all the images load up and the carousel and lightbox works perfectly.
My issue is when I click on an image, and it loads the new gallery, only the pictures in the carousel that are visible by default (options > visible: 4) work for lightbox, all the rest just link to the image itself.  It's like the new images are not part of the carousel, but it looks just like it does when it works when I look at it in firebug.

```
declareLightbox();
function declareLightbox() {
    $( ".lb_gallery" ).rlightbox();
}

declareCarousel();
function declareCarousel() {
    $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel({
    auto: {enabled: false},
    start: generatePages,
    visible: 4,
    pageLoaded: pageLoaded,
    width: 160,
    height: 120,
    margin:20
});
```

I had to modify the script that controls it a little bit to put the declarations inside of functions so that I could call them again from within the Ajax success call, and it seems to have worked fine for the carousel. Is there something else I need to call for lightbox, or am I missing something else entirely?

thanks

Comment: **Update**
I have managed to force the lightbox to be invoked on all the images now by redeclaring lightbox on the tag in the page click binding like so (pages are the little dots at the bottom to let you go between 'pages'

    .bind("click", {page: i},
 function( event ) {
         $( "#carousel" ).rcarousel( "goToPage", event.data.page );
         event.preventDefault();
         declareLightbox();
    }

So this works, but the counter on the lightbox when it comes up is completely wrong on any page but the first. ...

Comment: ...

Normally it says "x / y", where x=the sequence number of the pic and y= the total in that folder. Once you load a new carousel, 

x is still right,
but y is now whatever it was in the first one +4 

because there are  more objects being added to lightbox.
I thought this was because of where I am redeclaring the lightbox, so I went back and it wasn't right before I added that, and I removed the ajax so it just uses the get, and it still does the same thing. Somehow this counter is persisting between pages and I have no idea why or how.